# Find path following edges with greatest value in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

Lets say, that in my graph I've got edges that have field called value. After selecting start vertex I would like to find path by always selecting the edge that has the highest value. Unfortunatly I can't figure out how to write proper query, is it possible in ArangoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am unsure what you would like to achieve, there are two possible scenarios that i can imagine from your description:

First: Shortest Path

The use-case here is you know the starting vertex and the target vertex, and you want to find the shortest (or cheapest) path between those two.
The built in `SHORTEST_PATH` (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/shortest-path/) feature can serve it by defining the distance attribute in the options like this:

```
FOR v IN OUTBOUND @start TO @end @@edgeCollections OPTIONS {weightAttribute: "value", defaultWeight: 1}
  RETURN v
```

This will give you all vertices on the path from start to end which has the lowest some of value attributes. If you need the "highest value" you could copy the value and save it again with `1/value` in a different field, to find the path with the fewest edges having in total the highest sum of `values`

Second: Sorting of edges

The use case is you only have the starting vertex and want to get the connected vertices, ordered by the value on the edges. There you can simply combine the traversal statement with a simple sort. (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/traversals/l):

```
FOR v, e IN OUTBOUND @start @@edgeCollection
  SORT e.value DESC
  LIMIT 1 /* Only pick the highest one */
  REUTRN {v: v, e: e}
```

Third use-case: Iterating several depth only using the highest value

The AQL in Use-case 2 can be chained up to an arbitrary depth which has to be known a-priori. So say you would like to iterate 3 steps only using the edge with highest value:

```
FOR v1, e1 IN OUTBOUND @start @@edgeCollection
  SORT e1.value DESC
  LIMIT 1 /* Only pick the highest one */
  /* Depth 1 done. now depth 2*/
  FOR v2, e2 IN OUTBOUND v1 @@edgeCollection
    SORT e2.value DESC
    LIMIT 1 /* Only pick the highest one */
    FOR v3, e3 IN OUTBOUND v2 @@edgeCollection
      SORT e3.value DESC
      LIMIT 1 /* Only pick the highest one */
      RETURN [v1,v2,v3]
```

Forth use-case:

The depth is not known a-priori, in this case pure AQL in the currently release version (3.1) cannot formulate this. It will be easier to use a Foxx service (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/foxx-microservices/) using the traversal module *(note: no longer available)* in JavaScript which is a bit more flexible, but can only be implemented in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but unfortunately your solutions doesn't fit my use case, so let me clarify.

Comment: In second scenario you wrote there is a limit for entire all of the edges that  will be vistited during search. I would like to get one highest valye edge on each level. So sort and limit should be executed at each level and if the edges on each next level should be choosed from vertex with the highest value on the previous one. 
F.e. from graph: A -> { B, C }, B-> D, C -> E , where edge A->B has higher value than A->C I would like to get A -> B -> D

Comment: Have a look at the Foxx microservices in ArangoDB, you could do it there, as it allows you to make multiple single depth queries, always following the edge with the highest 'value' on it. And it is very fast :) If you want to stop looping in edges that form a 'circle' just keep an array of all the vertices you've visited and if you get a duplicate, stop iterating and return the result.

Comment: I'm using the java api for ArangoDB. I will try to test it and see performance how well it will perform. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, with the Foxx framework it can publish a REST API with an endpoint that lets you do the query. If you were doing this with a typical RDBMS you'd have to use stored procedures. Foxx is the tool ArangoDB gives you if you need that extra logic/control, but Foxx is much more functional than a simple stored procedure. The more you use them the more you love them.

Comment: Hi i just updated my answer, hope this halps and David Thomas is right, for some traversals AQL is not (yet) flexible enough and the best way to do it will be in a Foxx service.